# How do I use SAML to connect AWS Cognito to a remote Shibboleth install?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, saml, amazon-cognito, shibboleth

**Disclaimer**: I am not well-versed in how Shibboleth or other authentication systems or AWS Cognito works, so for anyone that can help, please explain things in simple terms.

My company recently got a cloud version of our product running on AWS, and we now want to use AWS Cognito and SAML to connect to a remote Shibboleth system to authenticate users logging into our cloud system. The Shibboleth system is located remotely at a client's institution.

Thus far, I've done the following (and I don't know if any of this is correct):

1. In AWS, I created an IAM Identity Provider of the type SAML. I received a `SAML.xml` file from the client's IT department, which I connected to the IAM Identity Provider. This seems okay.
2. When I set up the IAM Identity Provider, AWS autocreated Cognito Auth and Unauth roles, for which I kept the default policies.
3. I set up a new Federated Identity for the client institution. I also linked the created IAM Identity Provider to this Federated Identity.
4. Upon creating the Federated Identity, I was taken to a **Sample Code** page in AWS, where I needed to pick the SDK to use for making a connection, etc. I also got an Identity Pool ID from AWS. I opted to use the JavaScript SDK, so I downloaded the JS SDK as well as another recommended library on GitHub called `amazon-cognito-js-master`.
5. I included the necessary JS scripts in a new HTML file and then put the JS code below in the file (with a valid Identity Pool ID).
6. When I ran the script, I seemed to get back a valid `syncClient` object from the `console.log` statement, but from there, I have no clue what to do.

Basically, what do I have to do at this point to make a request from our JS script to the remote Shibboleth system to authenticate a user?

Do I need to have the user's credentials (i.e., username and password) already available before I make an `AWS.CognitoSyncManager` request, or is there some level of initialization required before that? Is there other information/files I need from the client's institution / IT department to get this set up?

I know so little about this, I'm not even sure which questions to ask. Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Please note that I have already looked extensively at the AWS docs, but I couldn't make any sense out of what they were saying (I'm not an authentication expert). Thank you.

```
var IdentityPoolId = 'us-east-2:45679821-9064-45f8-12ac-456132abc789'; // Not a real ID.

// Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider
AWS.config.region = 'us-east-2'; // Region
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  IdentityPoolId: IdentityPoolId,
});

// Initialize the Cognito Sync client

AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){

  var syncClient = new AWS.CognitoSyncManager();

  console.log(syncClient);

  syncClient.openOrCreateDataset('myDataset', function(err, dataset) {

    dataset.put('myKey', 'myValue', function(err, record){

      dataset.synchronize({

        onSuccess: function(data, newRecords) {
          // Your handler code here
        }

      });

    });

  });

});
```

Answer (score 2):

- **Basically, what do I have to do at this point to make a request from our JS script to the remote Shibboleth system to authenticate a user?**
  Well, you can not. When using Federated Identities, you need to write your own code to display the login UI or redirect to the login page of third-party IdPs like Shibboleth or use their SDK. Ultimately, you need to write your own code, without any AWS SDK to get OpenID tokens or as in your case, SAML assertions. When you do get a token or SAML assertion, use this in the Login map while initializing CognitoIdentityCredentials. See the example [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html#constructor-property). There is a *Logins* field where you need to pass the token or assertion received from your IdP. Now, as long as the SAML assertion in the map is valid, you can get temporary AWS credentials & your AWS calls will succeed. This one line in the Login map is the only interaction between Cognito & your Idp like Shibboleth when using Federated Identities. You can not directly make a call from Cognito Federated Identities to Shibboleth with username & password to get a valid token or response.
- **But what if I want to build an app or a service which needs authentication using Shibboleth. Ideally, if the user is not signed in, I should be shown a UI which should redirect me to Shibboleth where I can enter my username & password. Afterwords, I should be redirected to my app/service with valid credentials.**
  This can be done too but using Cognito Userpool and not Federated Identities. Add your SAML provider to a Userpool (see [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-saml-idp.html)). After this, add the Userpool to your Identity Pool (Federated Identities). Now use the built-in UI of Userpool to login and get the Id token (and not SAML assertion, User --> Userpool built-in UI--> Shibboleth --> Username+Password to login --> Shibboleth sends SAML assertion to Cognito userpool--> Userpool issues a token). Use this Id token in the login map of your CognitoIdentityCredentials.

Comment: agent420, thank you so much for your thorough response. I read it about 10 times as well as read over the links you provided, but I'm still confused and have some questions: 1) What is the difference between a Federated Identity and a User Pool? Or rather, what are they to begin with? What's the purpose of them? 2) It sounds like I still need additional information from the client institution's Shibb system. Specifically, it sounds like I still need the user to log in through their IdP login web page and have that send the SAML assertion back? Is that true? Or...

Comment: Do I already have everything I need from the client institution when they provided me with the SAML XML file that I linked to the Federated Identity? 3) This may sound like a silly question, but why do I need tokens? Ultimately, if a user is properly authenticated through their institution's IdP and SSO, then we trust that they are valid, and at that point, all we really want to do is get the user's internal ID, email address, etc. so that we can further authenticate them in our system and then allow them to log in with the necessary permissions. To that...

Comment: Should I continue to use the Federated Identity that I already created, or should I create a User Pool instead? This kind of goes back to question #1, but I'm just confused as to what's fundamentally happening under the hood with Cognito and what's authenticating what and telling which system that everything is okay or not, etc. Thank you.

Comment: Userpool is an Identity Provider (IdP) . You can use it to sign up/manage users and it can be used for login. Federated Identities (Identity Pools or Id Pools in short) use various IdPs and can be used to get temporary credentials. Userpool is for Authentication; Identity Pool for Authorization. Userpool is used to login users and get a token. Id Pools use the token as input and vend temporary AWS credentials. Id Pools do not have any concept of users. I know you mentioned you have looked at the docs.

Comment: I would suggest taking the help of someone well-versed in authentication as this is a critical part of any app.

Comment: You do need to login your users using your IdPs login page. It is just like Login with Google/Facebook. When you click on these buttons, you are redirected to their site.

Comment: The SAML file given by your Idp does indeed have everything u need. Tokens are used to verify that you are authenticated. Unlike server-side lang like PHP in which you can use sessions after login, javascript based apps need some other way to verify that a user is logged in i.e they have a valid session. This is done using JWT token which contain relevant claims like email, userid etc. in encoded format alongwith a signature. Again, I would recommend taking the help of someone well versed in these things

Comment: agent420, thanks a lot for all of your responses. I'd upvote all of them 100 times if I could. Also, I completely agree that I'd like to get someone who's an expert on all of this stuff to help out, but that may not be an option. To that, some follow-up questions: 1) Based on what you said, it sounds like I want to use a User Pool, not a Federated Identity, because I don't care about authorizing a user, per se, because that's done in our system. Instead, I want to authenticate the user and get their email address or something unique about them back so we can further check their credentials...

Comment: In our DB. Would you agree with that? Or is it one of those things where you're supposed to always use both User Pools and Federated Identities? Also, if we only care about authentication, then maybe we don't care about getting a token to send back via a Federated Identity, right? 2) To #1 above, I tried to start creating a User Pool in Cognito, but it started asking me all sorts of questions like, "What do you want users to log in with?", "What password strength do you want?" etc. Basically, it seems like it's asking me to set up the authentication on my side, as I think you said before.

Comment: To confirm what you said in a comment above, I don't need to do any of that, right? I should just redirect a user to the Shibb SSO webpage at their client institution, and then talk to the IT folks over there to get them to send back the necessary information to our system so that we can then do what we need to do though, right? This seems to be in-line with what you suggested in a comment above, but if we do that, it doesn't seem like we need to use AWS Cognito, User Pools, Federated Identities or any of that, which seems wrong. Again, any clarity would be eternally grateful. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, based on your use-case (just authentication & that too using Shibboleth  only), I don't see the point in using Cognito. Just Shibboleth's built in UI/API/SDKs if any (I am not familiar with Shibboleth ) should be more than enough. However, if you do want to use Cognito for any reason, Userpool would be more than enough. No need for federated identities.

Comment: So, yes  should just redirect a user to the Shibb SSO webpage and after login they would be redirected to your website. In their response, they would have values like email, username, phone etc. according to the settings configured. No need for Cognito at all if you just want to authenticate users in your application using Shibboleth as an IdP